# How is that correct: "speed is faster" or "prices are cheaper"

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

Read in a somewhat reliable source - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clearing_(finance):

```
speed of trades is much faster...
```

Also heard once or twice:

```
prices in this store are cheaper
```

Does it sound right for native speakers to say so, not "speed is higher" or "prices are lower"?

Comment: How is it incorrect?

Comment: It's tautological, but established as acceptable by use, at least in informal registers.

Comment: @MattЭллен it's incorrect for the same reason it's incorrect to say that a basketball player's height is much taller than a jockey's.  The height is not tall; the person is.

Answer (score 2):

This grates on my ear.  I would say:

> ... speed of trades is much higher ...

or

> ... trades are much faster ...

and

> ... prices in this store are much lower ...

I would not, however, say "this store is much cheaper," because it would likely imply inferior quality in addition to lower prices.

Answer (score 0):

"Speed" is fast or slow, so "speed of" something is "faster" or "slower".

"Price" is low ("cheap") or high ("expensive").

Notice that both sentences should have the word "than" following, because both are making comparisons.

I wouldn't complain if someone said, "That car's speed is higher than the other's".

Comment: "speed is higher" sounds more natural to me, but I correlate it with my native language (actually it is "speed is bigger" in my language). Still I do never try to rely on parallels, when using foreign language as each has it's own favour.